# Flex/ActionScript - rotate Sprite around its center

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I have created a Sprite in Actionscript and rendered it to a Flex Canvas. Suppose:

```
var fooShape:Sprite = new FooSpriteSubclass();

fooCanvas.rawChildren.addChild(myshape);

//Sprite shape renders on screen

fooShape.rotation = fooNumber;
```

This will rotate my shape, but seems to rotate it around the upper-left
point of its parent container(the canvas).

How can I force the Sprite to rotate about is own center point? I could obviously
write code to calculate the rotation, and then have it re-render, but I think there
must be a built-in way to do this, and certainly do not want to 'reinvent the wheel'
if possible.

I am using FlexBuilder, and therefore do not have access to the full Flash API.

Thank you much!

Answer (score 11):

The following steps are required to rotate objects based on a reference point (using [Matrix](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Matrix.html) object and getBounds):

1. Matrix translation (moving to the reference point)
2. Matrix rotation
3. Matrix translation (back to original position)

For example to rotate an object 90 degrees around its center:

```
// Get the matrix of the object  
var matrix:Matrix = myObject.transform.matrix; 

// Get the rect of the object (to know the dimension) 
var rect:Rectangle = myObject.getBounds(parentOfMyObject); 

// Translating the desired reference point (in this case, center)
matrix.translate(- (rect.left + (rect.width/2)), - (rect.top + (rect.height/2))); 

// Rotation (note: the parameter is in radian) 
matrix.rotate((90/180)*Math.PI); 

// Translating the object back to the original position.
matrix.translate(rect.left + (rect.width/2), rect.top + (rect.height/2));
```

Key methods used:

- [Matrix.rotate](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Matrix.html#rotate())
- [Matrix.translate](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Matrix.html#translate())
- [DisplayObject.getBounds](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#getBounds())

Comment: it'll be nice to parametrize the deg to rad conversion in case someone (like me) doesn't have it clear. ie: 
    rad_angle = angle*(Math.PI/180) 
Also, the factor can be cached for speed.

Also reusing the matrix works, but i needed to reasign the matrix to the object. (at least on html5 & neko)

Answer (score 5):

Didn't have much luck with the other examples.  This one worked for me. I used it on a UIComponent.

http://www.selikoff.net/2010/03/17/solution-to-flex-image-rotation-and-flipping-around-center/

```
private static function rotateImage(image:Image, degrees:Number):void {
// Calculate rotation and offsets
var radians:Number = degrees * (Math.PI / 180.0);
var offsetWidth:Number = image.contentWidth/2.0;
var offsetHeight:Number =  image.contentHeight/2.0;

// Perform rotation
var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.translate(-offsetWidth, -offsetHeight);
matrix.rotate(radians);
matrix.translate(+offsetWidth, +offsetHeight);
matrix.concat(image.transform.matrix);
image.transform.matrix = matrix;
```

}

Comment: your example works great, check out my other comment, maybe yours didint work because you needed to reassing the matrix. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/993445/flex-actionscript-rotate-sprite-around-its-center#comment62304621_1787534

Answer (score 0):

Actually I had to add this code to make above solutions work for me.

```
private var _rotateCount = 0;
var _origginalMatrix:Matrix=new Matrix();
.........
if (_rotateCount++ >= 360 / angleDegrees)
{
    myObject.transform.matrix = _origginalMatrix;
    _rotateCount = 0;
            return;
}

var matrix:Matrix = myObject.transform.matrix;
....
```

Without that after some long time rotated object slowly moves somewhere right top.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to rotate around the center, merely center the asset inside your sprite by setting the internal assets x and y to half of the width and height of the asset.  This swill center your content and allow it to rotate around a center point.

An example of runtime loaded assets is as follows:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader():
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(path/to/asset.ext);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, _onLoaderComplete);
loader.load(request);

private function _onLoaderComplete(e:Event):void
{
    var mc:MovieClip = e.target.content as MovieClip;
    mc.x = -mc.width * 0.5;
    mc.y = -mc.height * 0.5;
    mc.rotation = 90;
    addChild(mc);
}
```

Comment: That is not what was asked for

Answer (score -1):

An alternative solution is to put your object inside another View, move it so that your image's center is at the container's top-left corner, and then rotate the container.

```
import spark.components.*;

var myContainer:View = new View();
var myImage:Image = new Image();

myContainer.addElement(myImage);
myImage.x = myImage.width / -2;
myImage.y = myImage.height / -2;

addElement(myContainer);

myContainer.rotation = whateverAngle;
```

One issue might be that the width of the image isn't know at the moment it is created, so you might want to find a way around that. (Hardcode it, or see if myImage.preliminaryWidth works)

Answer (score -1):

```
/**
* Rotates the object based on its center
* Parameters: @obj => the object to rotate
* @ rotation => angle to rotate
* */
public function RotateAroundCenter(obj:Object, rotation:Number):void
{

var bound:Rectangle = new Rectangle();
// get the bounded rectangle of objects
bound = obj.getRect(this);

// calculate mid poits
var midx1:Number = bound.x + bound.width/2;
var midy1:Number = bound.y + bound.height/2;

// assign the rotation
obj.rotation = rotation;

// assign the previous mid point as (x,y)
obj.x = midx1;
obj.y = midy1;

// get the new bounded rectangle of objects
bound = obj.getRect(this);

// calculate new mid points
var midx2:Number = bound.x + bound.width/2;
var midy2:Number = bound.y + bound.height/2;

// calculate differnece between the current mid and (x,y) and subtract
 //it to position the object in the previous bound.
var diff:Number = midx2 - obj.x;
obj.x -= diff;
diff = midy2 - obj.y;
obj.y -= diff;
}

//////////////////
```

Usage:

you can use the above function as described below,

```
var img:Canvas = new Canvas()
RotateAroundCenter(img, rotation);
```

This will help you

REf: http://subashflash.blogspot.in/2010/08/rotation-of-object-based-on-center.html